# Bittrex websockets encoding method?

Tags: encoding, base64, decoding, cryptocurrency

It´s not a big deal to mimic the websocket connection made to bittrex from www, using chromes dev tools:

```
GET https://socket.bittrex.com/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22c2%22%7D%5D&_=1524596108843
```

This return a token

```
"ConnectionToken":"gbLsm8C6Jck1mQTTFjmuIv5qgUuMZz/kXU1s+fAnjnW
qUFQocNBfp3VOrd/y0acxWL5Fv7MZ54heRddLYZS+EMhLnaPPQiSZblvgJPCbLKqZTIkb"
```

That needs to be used with:

```
wss://socket.bittrex.com/signalr/connect? 
transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=
```

Then there are some commands sent to the websocket:

```
{"H":"c2","M":"SubscribeToSummaryLiteDeltas","A":[],"I":0}
{"H":"c2","M":"SubscribeToExchangeDeltas","A":["BTC-TRX"],"I":1}
{"H":"c2","M":"QueryExchangeState","A":["BTC-TRX"],"I":2}
```

Which makes bittrex stream data about the selected ticker, BTC-TRX. But here´s where things start to get odd:

Here´s what frames look like:

```
    {"C":"d-C95D047D-E,0|OHjr,0|OHjs,2|CW,6116","M":[{"H":"C2","M":"uE","A":["dY+7DsIwDEX/xXOI7NiOnYwwg0TpwENd+QnUfydtBQKp9ear4yPfFxyhwr4/7PruCgFOUJO4SoA71McL+lsLAnRQMeI0xhzg3EKXQpEFzUvyMayhiWaUOJtqLCZKonkcAly+cvyXl/lCHKOyaxbDdbUuamMXzhELk5lvvKE+s0yoyWPKVIhwg81LO8OcNCZOGQn5g9IPSuyLtq1To2drNIxv"]}]}
```

It certainly looks like base64, but decoding it gives me something like:

u���0E��s��؎��0�D��C]�    �'m����#��¾?���
NP��J�;���[tP1�4���B�B��K�1���f�8�j,&J�y\�r����B��k�u�.jc���o��>�L��c�T�p��K;Ü4&N ���J싶�S�gk4�o

Did anyone figure out how to turn this into readable data?

Answer (score 3):

To decode the encoded part of the response, proceed like so (below python 3.8.2 prompt):

```
>>> import zlib
>>> import base64
>>> val = b'dY+7DsIwDEX/xXOI7NiOnYwwg0TpwENd+QnUfydtBQKp9ear4yPfFxyhwr4/7PruCgFOUJO4SoA71McL+lsLAnRQMeI0xhzg3EKXQpEFzUvyMayhiWaUOJtqLCZKonkcAly+cvyXl/lCHKOyaxbDdbUuamMXzhELk5lvvKE+s0yoyWPKVIhwg81LO8OcNCZOGQn5g9IPSuyLtq1To2drNIxv'
>>> zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(val), -15)
b'{"M":"BTC-TRX","N":24854,"Z":[{"TY":2,"R":0.00000733,"Q":28491.34078928},{"TY":2,"R":0.00000721,"Q":136755.97451456}],"S":[{"TY":0,"R":0.00000739,"Q":480.53856470},{"TY":2,"R":0.00000751,"Q":738436.09317788},{"TY":2,"R":0.00000758,"Q":310528.26191108},{"TY":2,"R":0.00000763,"Q":70625.23260103},{"TY":1,"R":0.00001388,"Q":0.0}],"f":[]}'
```

Note the `-15` as second argument to the decompress method. With that argument, the `decompress` function corresponds to `rawInflate` in equivalent javascript libraries.

Answer (score -1):

The response appears to be (at least in a Python world) subject to `b64decode()` and `decompress()`.

```
message = decompress(b64decode(message))
```

Comment: @McNight Really? Nice! I tried different online php and python websites but couldnt find any where I´d get a valid result doing what you´re doing. You did indeed get something human readable out of this or are you just suggesting?

Comment: I'm not the author of the answer. I just formatted. The orignal author is @Mark.

Comment: Minus one. Because the answer is too cryptic to be useful. Please provide a working snippet of code. From which packages must the functions you mention be imported? What is "message" ... ?