# Bittrex websocket encoding

Tags: c#, python

i use this topic
[Bittrex websockets encoding method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011256/bittrex-websockets-encoding-method)

bittrex websocket api return json string.

```
{"C":"d-88903F9C-uIVg,2|Cv,81594","G":"f8N0wWnjI7HYfemJI8e0xCbSANWfxnpNCIT4iAHhWDhZjpcgeesgN6r5uUtMrGXJhuLnOyMI52yEsxDhlxcpAJc6+oPWpOx4b7k2EWza50QZM5sNKXQHzanncDgQPzJQc7yWAg==","M":[]}
```

I want decode param **G**(OpenBuyOrders). Firstly i think its gzip string, but decoding method not works
I use python method

```
gzip.decompress(binascii.a2b_base64(b"f8N0wWnjI7HYfemJI8e0xCbSANWfxnpNCIT4iAHhWDhZjpcgeesgN6r5uUtMrGXJhuLnOyMI52yEsxDhlxcpAJc6+oPWpOx4b7k2EWza50QZM5sNKXQHzanncDgQPzJQc7yWAg=="))
```

its raise error. 
I try make it with c#. Same error. In documentation i not find about this format

```
public static string Decode(string wireData)
        {
            try
            {
                // Step 1: Base64 decode the wire data into a gzip blob
                byte[] gzipData = Convert.FromBase64String(wireData);

                // Step 2: Decompress gzip blob into minified JSON
                using (var decompressedStream = new MemoryStream())
                using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(gzipData))
                using (var deflateStream = new DeflateStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    deflateStream.CopyTo(decompressedStream);
                    decompressedStream.Position = 0;

                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(decompressedStream))
                    {
                        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "";
            }

        }
```

Comment: what is the exception being thrown?

Comment: @BrettCaswell {"Unknown block type. Stream may be corrupted."}

Comment: hmm.. for c#, what are you using for your signalr client? is it establishing a websocket connection or is it long polling?

Comment: @BrettCaswell i want simply decode this json. I establish ws connection, but not share code.